# how does Unix timestamps account for Daylight savings?

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I've been researching how a Unix timestamp can account for daylight savings and there seems to be a lot of convoluted answers on here about that it doesn't matter or just set it to europe/london or use a function getting the local time. This still does not account for daylight savings! here is some test code:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
$timestamp_time = date("hi", 1377853200);

echo $timestamp_time;
```

This will return the timestamp's hour and minutes an hour faster than it actually is (it is set to 9am, comes back 10am). This timestamp was made using an online converter set to GMT (+0), I have used various converters so it's not just this one being broken. I MUST use GMT for the project this is for. Can anybody clarify how I can allow for daylight savings or is it already allowed for? Also a quick explanation why it does what does would be very useful.

I suppose then finally I need to know how to proceed, do I use my code to allow for it eg if winter months -1 hour in summer months +1hour? this seems a ridiculous solution... Any help would be great.
Thank You.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The unix timestamp does not contain any timezone data. It is UTC and has no DST settings.

You should convert the time (e.g. with the DateTime() and DateTimeZone() classes in php) internally to the correct timezone and it will automatically adjust for DST and timezone offset based on the date.

Comment: Here is an implementation with DateTime based on the code given :)

`$date = new DateTime("@1377853200",new DateTimeZone("Europe/London"));
echo $date->format('hi');`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting appropriate locale with `setlocale` and then parsing out the date with `strftime`. php.net has a fairly detailed example on how to achieve this here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php . `strftime` takes a timestamp as a parameter, so no conversions needed there.

Your code would look like something along the lines of

```
setlocale("en_GB"); // example

$timestamp_time = strftime("%H%M", 1377853200);

echo $timestamp_time;
```

Comment: so you know this still returns it an hour fast :P

Comment: did you check for the proper timezone string for your operating system and locale on the page I linked to, or copy/pasted? :)

Comment: yes double checked. don't worry, the fella above solved it :)

Comment: Good that you solved your problem, but I'm left with another - why something that worked reliably for years for me and others suddenly won't work on an isolated machine somewhere :)

Comment: `strftime` does not convert timestamps to timezones.  It converts time strings to languages only.  Same thing with `setlocale` -- it's just changing your preferred language.